# Woocommerce cmb2 taxonomy_select Не находит категории

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'           => 'Категории',
    'desc'           => 'Выберите категорию',
    'id'             => 'product_set',
    'taxonomy'       => 'my-custom-cat-slug', //Enter Taxonomy Slug
    'type'           => 'taxonomy_select',
    'remove_default' => 'true', // Removes the default metabox provided by WP core.

    // Optionally override the args sent to the WordPress get_terms function.
    'query_args' => array(
        'include' => array(102)
        // 'orderby' => 'slug',
        // 'hide_empty' => true,
    ),
) );
```

Пытался через `'query_args'` по id добавить, но ничего не получилось. В админке просто пустой селект. Но если пишу Рубрику из записей - тогда выводит. Как написать правильно, чтобы находил категории указанные?